# Displaying Nullable Boolean Input In UI

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

I currently have an advanced search page that searches a number of fields in my database. It has several textboxes that all search different fields, the user has the option to leave textboxes blank and they will be ignored from the search.

The problem is I now want to add to this to also search some of my BIT fields, my original idea was to use checkboxes for this. the problem I have is that I now realise I need 3 states N/A, True, False as the user needs the ability not to search on this field. The only real idea I have is something like a dropdown or radio list with these 3 options in. However there could end up being 5+ inputs searching BIT fields and I'm not sure if this would get messy. I remember when I used to develop windows apps a checkbox could also have a null/not selected state I'm not sure if there is any alternative for the web? I didn't really want to have to right a custom control if anything exists?

I just wondered if anyone had any suggestions as to how they would design this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox in the web world only have 2 state : check or unchecked

you could do like in reporting services where you have a checkbox to indicate if the field is used in the search next to radio for yes and no, but this would get messy.

I would go with a dropdown with All, Yes and No options. with All being the default option.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do it with two radio buttons per option (yes/true and no/false) with neither selected by default - this would allow a user to leave them blank and ignore them, or select one of the options.

The only real issue with this is how to reset them back to nothing once the user's selected one - which would either need a "Clear all" button, which would reset all the choices, or you're back to a list with three options - either a radio or drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable Boolean has 3-states. Use 3 radio buttons so the user doesn't have to click twice as they would have to do with a dropdownlist. Also they can undo setting the checkbox to false, which they can't do if they only have a checkbox.

A clean intuitive way to show the results is a checkbox or nothing.

For MVC3 put the following C# Razor code in the Views|Shared|DisplayTemplates|Boolean.cshtml file to automagically show a checked checkbox when true, an unchecked checkbox when false, and nothing (`&nbsp;`) if null. Null typically means the user is undecided, not sure, or thinks the question you're asking is private and none of your business.

```
@model bool?
@{
    //ForDisplay Template - similar template for EditFor

    Dictionary<string, object> cbAttr = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 


    cbAttr.Add("id", ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""));


    if (Model.HasValue && Model.Value)
    {

       cbAttr.Add("checked", "checked");
       @Html.CheckBox(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""), cbAttr);
    }
    else if (Model.HasValue && !Model.Value)
    {
        @Html.CheckBox(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""), cbAttr);
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DisplayText("&nbsp;");
    }
}
```

For MVC3 put the following C# Razor code in the Views|Shared|EditorTemplates|Boolean.cshtml file to automagically show the 3-radio buttons.

```
@model bool?
<div data-ui="buttonset">
@{
    Dictionary<string, object> yesAttrs = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
    Dictionary<string, object> noAttrs = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
    Dictionary<string, object> nullAttrs = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 

    yesAttrs.Add("id", ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("") + "Yes");
    noAttrs.Add("id", ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("") + "No");
    nullAttrs.Add("id", ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("") + "NA");

    if (Model.HasValue && Model.Value)
    {
        yesAttrs.Add("checked", "checked");
    }
    else if (Model.HasValue && !Model.Value)
    {
        noAttrs.Add("checked", "checked");
    }
    else
    {
        nullAttrs.Add("checked", "checked");
    }
}

@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "true", yesAttrs) 
  <label for="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""))Yes">Yes</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "false", noAttrs) 
  <label for="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""))No">No</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "null", nullAttrs) 
  <label for="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""))NA">TBD</label>
</div>
```